# How do I remove custom currencies in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

In Google Sheets, you can add custom currency things under the formatting tab and google sheets with keep them saved. I was playing around with this function and added a few ones to test it out but now I can figure out how to get them to disappear, can anyone help me delete them? You can see the currencies I want to delete at the bottom of the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove them - you can only override them with other formattings. Google Sheets stores last 3 custom formattings for possible future re-usage which can be only overridden by other 3 custom formattings of your choice in this area:

[image: 0]